# Delphi TeeChart - print preview and save dialog

Tags: delphi, teechart

I'm using the built in TeeChart in Delphi XE for graphs.

When I just put a graph on a form, I have all these options to export/save or print preview, but those aren't there at runtime.

I want to add a button for a save dialog and a print preview (right now I just have it doing Chart1.Print and Chart1.SaveToBitmapFile)

I googled around and I found this link: http://www.steema.com/support/faq/NewVCL/FAQ_VCL_DIALOGS.htm

So I added EditChar to Uses and added the line
    EditChart(Self,Chart1 );

but when I try to compile, it gives me errors:

```
[DCC Error] E1026 File not found: 'TeeBackImage.DFM'
[DCC Error] E1026 File not found: 'TeeEmbossEditor.DFM'
[DCC Error] E1026 File not found: 'TeeMargins.DFM'
[DCC Error] E1026 File not found: 'TeeMouseCursor.DFM'
[DCC Error] E1026 File not found: 'TeeStringsEditor.DFM'
```

Also I've added Uses TeePrevi, but it says ChartPreview is an undeclared identifier

Does anyone know what's going on? Creating a chart and printing/saving works fine, and the errors seem to happen when I add Uses EditChar

Thanks

Comment: For the save dialog part, isn't a `TSaveDialog` enough?

Comment: The form has a bunch of different options to select graph type and customize it, and I want to save or export the graph itself. Wouldnt TSaveDialog just save the entire form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run-time chart editor, print preview & exporting dialogs are not available in TeeChart VCL Standard, which is the version shipped in Delphi, and therefore necessary units are not included. To be able to do so you'll need TeeChart Professional VCL. [Here](http://www.steema.com/linkIn/TeeChartForXE2) you'll find the TeeChart landing page for RAD Studio users with a grid comparing Std and Pro versions, access to the fully functional Pro evaluation version, etc.

Answer (score 6):

I am using Delphi XE2 with TeeChart Standard (as included with XE2)

I added  "VCLTee.TeeEdiGene, VCLTee.EditChar" to the uses list and then I added the lines:

```
ChartPreview(Self,Chart1);
```

and

```
EditChart(Self,Chart1 );
```

to my code to bring up the preview and edit dialogs.  It seems to work OK

Comment: For C++ XE3: include VCLTee.TeeEditCha.hpp and VCLTee.TeeEdiGene.hpp