# Delphi Firemonkey Programmatic Data File Export to Excel -- Where are the units and methods?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, teechart

TeeChart can export data from the chart editor (tcharteditor). In VCL and (judging from documentation) .net, one can programmatically export using the

```
chart1.export
```

command. I am looking to do the same from TeeChart FireMonkey. What unit adds such a command? Shouldn't there be Chart1.Export?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7336170/2292722) to a similar question, which explains some differences between standard and professional versions of `TeeChart` (standard is the one included for free in Delphi). Here's a [link](https://www.steema.com/feature_matrix/vcl) to a feature table on Steema's site

Comment: I'm using TeeChart Professional, have used the various examples both in the documentation and on StackOverflow, and still come up empty. Exploring if having xvalue.name strings with embedded spaces and parentheses might be the problem.